# Custom Account authenticator. Cleanup after account is removed from device

Tags: android, accountmanager

Is there a way to get some kind of notification/broadcast/etc. when a custom account is removed from "Accounts & sync settings"?

The application I have can facilitate multiple users on a device (this is for a corporate use) and uses a single SQLite database. Say I create multiple users for my application on a device and populate database with data that is relevant only to those two users. My problem here is that if one of the user is removed from "Accounts & sync settings" I have no way to cleanup database and/or some external files on SD card.

I could duplicate user information in a redundant table and compare it with registered accounts and then removing user data from the database if user information in the table and Account[] array from AccountManager does not match. Feels dirty to me.

Comment: what about getAccountRemovalAllowed in your Authenticator class that is extending AbstractAccountAuthenticator? like http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/40943209facc#sample%2fsrc%2fpl%2fselvin%2fandroid%2fListSyncSample%2fauthenticator%2fAuthenticator.java

Comment: That works better than the accepted answer...thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have two options:

1. You can use the `addOnAccountsUpdatedListener` method of `AccountManager` to add a listener in the `onCreate` method of an `Activity` or `Service` -- make sure you remove the listener in your `onDestroy` method (i.e. do NOT use this in an endlessly running service) or the `Context` used to retrieve the `AccountManager` will never be garbage collected
2. The `AccountsService` will broadcast an intent with the action `AccountManager.LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION` every time an account is added, removed or changed which you can add a receiver for.

Comment: Pity it doesn't supply removed account info, but it is possible to work around that. Thanks!

Comment: Yes it just gives you the list of the current accounts.

Comment: Third option which provides the Account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214789/does-syncadapter-get-notified-when-accountmanager-removes-account/16651562#16651562

Comment: 2. option is now deprecated from API 26: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION

Answer (score 3):

I didn't see a lot of examples on how people implement account cleanup, so I thought I would post my solution (really a variation of the accepted answer).

```
public class AccountAuthenticatorService extends Service {
    private AccountManager _accountManager;
    private Account[] _currentAccounts;
    private OnAccountsUpdateListener _accountsUpdateListener = new OnAccountsUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAccountsUpdated(Account[] accounts) {

            // NOTE: this is every account on the device (you may want to filter by type)
            if(_currentAccounts == null){
                _currentAccounts = accounts;
                return;
            }

            for(Account currentAccount : _currentAccounts) {
                boolean accountExists = false;
                for (Account account : accounts) {
                    if(account.equals(currentAccount)){
                        accountExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(!accountExists){
                    // Take actions to clean up.  Maybe send intent on Local Broadcast reciever
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public AccountAuthenticatorService() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);

        // set to true so we get the current list of accounts right away.
        _accountManager.addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(_accountsUpdateListener, new Handler(), true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       _accountManager.removeOnAccountsUpdatedListener(_accountsUpdateListener);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        AccountAuthenticator authenticator = new AccountAuthenticator(this);
        return authenticator.getIBinder();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've implemented this, but never gets hit. I add an account explicitly then go and remove it from accounts. Doesn't get hit at all. Even if I remove other accounts

Comment: Assuming everything with the `Service` has been setup it could be that the API is a little different?  Have you tried using the API level 26 version that takes account types?

Comment: Another option might be to wrap the `OnAccountsUpdateListener` listener in livedata. `onActive`, call `addOnAccountsUpdatedListener` and onInactive call `removeOnAccountsUpdatedListener`. Then observe the livedata