# How to get notified when an account is add to or remove from device?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, account, accountmanager, android-account

I want to set a `BroadcastReceiver` to get notified when an account is removed from the device. What `IntentFilter` should I use in my `BroadcastReceiver`. I couldn't find any related intent.

Thanks

Comment: you can try account manager for notification of account removal here is a link for helping you :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214789/does-syncadapter-get-notified-when-accountmanager-removes-account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11214789/does-syncadapter-get-notified-when-accountmanager-removes-account), I found that there is an intent called: [`LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#LOGIN_ACCOUNTS_CHANGED_ACTION). Here is the documentation:

> Action sent as a broadcast Intent by the AccountsService when accounts
>   are added, accounts are removed, or an account's credentials (saved
>   password, etc) are changed.

It worked correctly. Also there is another option that is using [`addOnAccountsUpdatedListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#addOnAccountsUpdatedListener(android.accounts.OnAccountsUpdateListener,%20android.os.Handler,%20boolean))